# Unknown depth nested maps check key existence and get value

Tags: java

I have a hashmap of the following structure:-

```
mymap = {a:{b:{c:{d:{e}}}}
```

How do I check the existance of key "d" in hashmap mymap in the simplest way?
Is there any Java8 features that might come in handy here?

```
mymap.get( "a" )).get( "b" )..;
```

**is not going to work because I don't know the level in which d is nested.** 
How do I check if d is present in the map, and get its value without this trailing call? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [FasterXML-Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library, which gives you the simplicty of traversing over nesed json.

For example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // can reuse, share globally
String myMapJson = "{\"a\":{\"b\":{\"c\":{\"d\":{\"e\":\"\"}}}}"
JsonNode data = mapper.readTree(myMapJson);
boolean hasKey = data.has("d");
```

Or, if you already have the object as `Map` you can write it as `json` and then load it the same way above:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // can reuse, share globally
String jsonData = mapper.writeValueAsString(myMapObject);
JsonNode data = mapper.readTree(jsonData);
boolean hasKey = data.has("d");
if (hasKey) {
  JsonNode result = data.findValue("d");
}
```

Comment: Can i do a data.get? to fetch the value?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `get(String key)` to extract the value, but you'll receive `null` if the key does not exists, so you better use `path(String key)` in order to avoid the `null` value, and you will get an object calls `MissingNode`.
If you want get for the nested key, you may need to use: `findValue(String key)`

Comment: I get this: [java] com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('A' (code 65)): was expecting double-quote to start field name.
My field names do not strat with double -quotes. How do I bypass this?

Comment: What do you mean? if it is a `String` then is must to start with double quotes.

Comment: To me, the hasKey returns false. It is not able to find keys over a depth of 1 level

Answer (score 3):

I have recently had a similar problem and managed to come up with a solution which works with any JSON depths.

It is a solution which transforms the String into a JsonNode Object and then tries to find the parent value of a given fieldName (in this case 'd'). The result returning something which is not null, will tell you if the value exists or not.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String myMapJson = "{\"a\":{\"b\":{\"c\":{\"d\":{\"e\":\"\"}}}}"
JsonNode data = mapper.readTree(myMapJson);
if (((ObjectNode)data.findParent("d")) != null) {
  // Do something if value is found
} else {
  // Do something if value is not found
}
```

Hope this helps..